# How i can to save a json object from javascript to a php session variable?

Tags: php, json

Hi i need some examples about how i can to store an json object to php session variable.The json object as the follow:

```
var jsonObject={ "menu":
                         {
                            "intro":{
                                       "intosub":"sub_1"
                                     }
                              "vis":{
                                      "visub":"sub_2"
                                     }


}
```

regards

Comment: Well, you send the object in serialized form from client to server by means of an AJAX call. On the server side you store either the json string or the deserialized object into the session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have tried this way but i found errors, can you give me an examples?

Comment: Please post your code snippets along with the _exact_ error messages. Then we should be able to help. Without this question is a _guessing game_ and should be closed.

Comment: The question is simple, i would like to save an json objecte into php session, and finally retrieve it throught an other php file and to access their properties as a normal json object.

Comment: OK, no code, no details as asked, just a repetition. I am out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you gave us, your json object is wrong. It should be:

```
var jsonObject={
    "menu":
    {
        "intro":{
            "intosub":"sub_1"
        },
        "vis":{
            "visub":"sub_2"
        }
    }
};
```

## EDIT

> ```
> var jsonObject={ "menu": { "intro":{ "intosub":"sub_1" }, "vis":{ "visub":"sub_2" } }
> var string=JSON.stringify(jsonobject);
> var phpcode="<?php $_SESSION["jsonObject"]= " phpcode+=string+"?>";
> ```

Javascript is client side when PHP is server side. That means that when you create your object with javascript, you can't interact with the server anymore until you use Ajax that allows the transmission of client side data to your server then send them again to the client if necessary.

What you did with your `var phpcode="<?php $_SESSION["jsonObject"]= " phpcode+=string+"?>"` is that you asked your server BEFORE it sends to the client to fill your "phpcode" JS variable with... I don't really understand what you tried here with setting a session variable but if you tried to set the PHP session variable with your json object like that, it is the same as if you set the PHP session variable directly without the use of JS.
However, I guess you want to fill your session variable with dynamic data you created with the use of JS or your question makes no sense.
What you need to understand is that when you write `<?php stuff; ?>` in javascript, when it is send to the client, it is as if you wrote stuff directly in your javascript. It's done and it won't change and certainly not communicate with your server.
Ex: `var math=<?php echo 10+1;?>;` is the same as if you wrote `var math=11;` directly in your JS. Of course, you use PHP to insert PHP stuff into your JS but once it's done and send to the client, it is set in stone and you use Ajax to change that.

What you need to do is to take your json object and use Ajax to send it to PHP.
I saw you are using Jquery so here is the Jquery doc about Ajax > https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

That will look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'path/to/a/PHP/file',
    data:{jsonobject:yourstringifyjsonobject}
});
```

You will retrieve that "jsonobject" in your "path/to/a/PHP/file" with $_POST['jsonobject'] and here you go:

```
session_start();//to not forget if you want session variables to work
$_SESSION['whatever']=json_decode($_POST['jsonobject'])
```

your session variable is set with your json object.

Comment: yes is truth, i just wanted to put any json object.sorry

Comment: Like arkascha, you tried the right way, using Ajax, and got errors but if you don't give us your bugged script, we can't help you and don't intend to write your stuff for you. If you want help, give us your script with your errors.

Comment: <!-- 'var jsonObject={ "menu":
                         {
                            "intro":{
                                       "intosub":"sub_1"
                                     },
                              "vis":{
                                      "visub":"sub_2"
                                     }


}

var string=JSON.stringify(jsonobject);
var phpcode="<?php 

$_SESSION["jsonObject"]=
"
phpcode+=string+"?>";'-->

Comment: Please edit the header post because comments are not for that purpose. I can say there is no Ajax call in this code. >.> Edit your OP and I will explain you what is your error.

Comment: Here you go, I explained everything. I comment here because I don't know if you will be warned.

Comment: thanks!, i will try to test this code and i will tell you something about it.

Comment: i have changed some  parts of code and now it's working. thanks!.

Comment: If I resolved your problem, can you mark my answer as accepted and maybe vote it up? It's the concept > https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers